Adding new VDI forces Ubuntu's reinstallation
I've started playing with virtualization using Oracle VM VirtualBox Manager and Ubuntu 20.04.6 but I faced some trouble. When I try to add a new VDI to my VM inside Storage setting as a IDE Controller (alongside the Ubuntu's optical drive) and run machine, I am asked for Ubuntu reinstallation, but when I remove this VDI (Zajecia_4) from the IDE Controller I am not asked for reinstallation. Below I attached the options I chose for VDI, optical drive and boot order's options.
ISO:

VDI:

boot order:

Did I miss something during configuration my VM, or maybe reinstallation is expected behavior in this scenario? What should I pay attention to when looking for errors in the logs?

I've resolved the issue by setting boot disk in bios.

More details please.

I just clicked the F12 button right at the beginning of the system startup and set boot disk to desire one.
